# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar registros iguales de una tabla de MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla *MySQL*:

[image]

... y hago la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM tesis WHERE carrera IN 
(SELECT carrera FROM tesis GROUP BY carrera HAVING COUNT(id_tesis) > 1) 
ORDER BY fecha desc;
```

y me muestra lo siguiente:

```
      CARRERA                              NOMBRE TESIS
```

> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa
>
> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa
>
> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa
>
> Ingeniería en TIC ------------------------------------La intranet dentro de las organizaciones
>
> Ingeniería en TIC ------------------------------------La intranet dentro de las organizaciones

¿Cómo hago para para que solo me muestre las licenciaturas en Administración como lo siguiente?:

```
      CARRERA                              NOMBRE TESIS
```

> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa
>
> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa
>
> Licenciatura Administración ----------------------Tesis en contabilidad Administrativa

Comment: Lo que necesitas son  las tesis de la misma carrera que tengan el mismo nombre ?

Comment: necesitamos que aclares la pregunta para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: Si lo que necesito son las tesis de la misma carrera que tengan el mismo nombre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si modificas la estructura de tus tablas:

CARRERA (Tabla)

id_carrera (pk), nombre_carrera

TESIS (Tabla)

id_tesis(pk), nombre_tesis, id_carrera(fk)

Y la consulta seria:

```
select t.nombre_tesis, c.nombre_carrera
   from tesis t  inner join  carrera c
          on id_carrera = c.id 
   where c.id = 1;

  # asumiendo que el codigo 1 corresponde a la carreraLicenciatura Administración
```

Comment: nunca pero nunca se hardcodea un codigo en una consulta...

Comment: nunca pero nunca se hardcodea un codigo en una consulta...

Comment: A que te refieres con  se hardcodea un codigo en una consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Agrega a la consulta un where para el campo que necesitas:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tesis 
WHERE 
    carrera IN (SELECT carrera FROM tesis GROUP BY carrera HAVING COUNT(id_tesis) > 1) 
  and 
    carrera = "Licenciatura Administración" 
ORDER BY fecha desc
```

Aclaro que lo anterior anda.. pero como solución es horrible.. pero sin mas información mas no se puede hacer.

Comment: Hola, vengo a darle énfasis a la parte de "como solución es horrible"...
q cochinaaaadaa.

PD: Hoy hice un in ('A','B','C') :P

Comment: O como puedo solucionarlo, como hago que me muestre solo los datos que se repiten?

Comment: Esta consulta no lo resuelve? No termino de entender que querds con el carrera in... por favor explica eso en la pregunta